# range-based for loop for private map values

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, generator

I have the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class MyObject
{
public:
    MyObject()
        : m_Items{ { 1, "one" },{ 2, "two" },{ 3, "three" } }
    {}

    RETURNTYPE GetStringIterator() const
    {
        IMPLEMENTATION
    }

private:
    std::map<int, std::string> m_Items;
};


int main()
{
    MyObject o;
    for (auto& s : o.GetStringIterator())
    {
        std::cout << s;
    }
}
```

What should `RETURNTYPE` and `IMPLEMENTATION` be in order to allow any client of `MyObject` (in this case the `main()` function), to iterate over the values of the `m_Items` map, without copying any data? It seems that this should be possible with c++11 range based for loops and iterators. but I have not been able to figure out how.

Comment: Is using Boost an option? If so, Boost.Range and its `boost::iterator_range` could be used.

Comment: Note that in C++, "Iterator" is a *position* in a range. I would name the function `GetStrings`

Comment: This is complete overthinking. `RETURNTYPE` should simply be `auto &`, and `IMPLEMENTATION` be `return m_items;`. Mission accomplished.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik _Should_ it be? Does that accomplish it? Is it possible that you're underthinking the problem? What if OP asked to iterate over the values because... maybe... OP just wants to iterate over the values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to first answer this in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14).

Here is a minimal mapping iteratoroid:

```
template<class F, class It>
struct iterator_mapped {
  decltype(auto) operator*() const {
    return f(*it);
  }

  iterator_mapped( F f_in, It it_in ):
    f(std::move(f_in)),
    it(std::move(it_in))
  {}

  iterator_mapped( iterator_mapped const& ) = default;
  iterator_mapped( iterator_mapped && ) = default;
  iterator_mapped& operator=( iterator_mapped const& ) = default;
  iterator_mapped& operator=( iterator_mapped && ) = default;

  iterator_mapped& operator++() {
    ++it;
    return *this;
  }
  iterator_mapped operator++(int) {
    auto copy = *this;
    ++*this;
    return copy;
  }
  friend bool operator==( iterator_mapped const& lhs, iterator_mapped const& rhs ) {
    return lhs.it == rhs.it;
  }
  friend bool operator!=( iterator_mapped const& lhs, iterator_mapped const& rhs ) {
    return !(lhs==rhs);
  }
private:
  F f;
  It it;
};
```

it is not technically an iterator, but it qualifies for `for(:)` loops.

```
template<class It>
struct range_t {
  It b, e;
  It begin() const { return b; }
  It end() const { return e; }
};
template<class It>
range_t<It> range( It b, It e ) {
  return {std::move(b), std::move(e)};
}
```

the above is an absolutely minimal iterator range type that can be `for(:)` iterated.

```
template<class F, class R>
auto map_range( F&& f, R& r ) {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  auto b = begin(r);
  auto e = end(r);
  using it = iterator_mapped<std::decay_t<F>, decltype(b)>;
  return range( it( f, b ), it( f, e ) );
}
```

note that `R&` not `R&&`; taking an rvalue for `r` here is dangerous.

```
auto GetStringIterator() const
{
  return map_range( [](auto&& pair)->decltype(auto){
    return pair.second;
  }, m_Items );
}
```

and done.

Converting this to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) is a pain.  You have to toss around `std::function`s in place of lambdas (or write function objects that do the task instead of a lambda), replace `decltype(auto)` with `auto` and trailing return types, give the exact type of `auto&&` arguments to lambdas, etc.  You end up with about 25%-50% more code, most of it obscure type chasing.

This is basically what `boost::adaptors::map_values` does, but this is hand-rolled so you can understand how it works and don't have a boost dependency.

Answer (score 8):

range-based iteration can be achieved like this:

```
class MyObject
{
public:
    MyObject()
        : m_Items{ { 1, "one" },{ 2, "two" },{ 3, "three" } }
    {}

    auto begin()       { return m_Items.begin(); }
    auto begin() const { return m_Items.begin(); }
    auto end()       { return m_Items.end(); }
    auto end() const { return m_Items.end(); }

private:
    std::map<int, std::string> m_Items;
};
```

Copying or not copying the value depends on how the code is written at the call site:

```
MyObject a;
for(auto [key,value] : a) {} // copies are made
for(auto & [key,value] : a) {} // no copy
for(auto const & [key,value] : a) {} // no copy
```

And you can disable the modification of map values by removing the non-const versions of `begin` and `end` :

```
class MyObject
{
public:
    MyObject()
        : m_Items{ { 1, "one" },{ 2, "two" },{ 3, "three" } }
    {}

    auto begin() const { return m_Items.begin(); }
    auto end() const { return m_Items.end(); }

private:
    std::map<int, std::string> m_Items;
};
```

Then, attempts at modifying the value in a range-for loop will lead to a compilation error:

```
MyObject a;
for(auto & [key,value] : a) {
    //value.push_back('a');      // Not OK 
}
for(auto & [key,value] : a) {
    cout << value;             // OK
}
```

Note that if the map is an implementation detail, the answer proposed by @Barry should be used, because it iterates only on the values of the map, not on the keys too.

Comment: I feel like this doesn't really answer the question. OP asked for a way to iterate over the values of the map. This solution iterates over the whole map. Perhaps OP is happy with this, but perhaps the map is just an implementation detail?

Comment: Indeed not the complete solution, but you answered another question I had, so thanks anyway:)

Comment: What versions of C++ allow the [key,value] syntax in the for loop? VS2015 doesn't appear to support it.

Comment: @jkokorian it's c++17

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`boost::adaptors::map_values`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/map_values.html), it works in C++11:

```
auto GetStringIterator() const
    // NB: have the move the declaration of m_Items ahead of this function for this to work
    -> decltype(m_Items | boost::adaptors::map_values)
{
    return m_Items | boost::adaptors::map_values;
}
```

Or its range-v3 equivalent, [`view::values`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/structranges_1_1v3_1_1view_1_1values__fn.html). Both can be used like `values(m)` instead of `m | values`, if you prefer it that way.

Either solution returns a *view* onto the values of the map. This is an object that doesn't own any of its underlying elements and is cheap to copy - that is, O(1). We're not coyping the map, or any of its underlying elements.

You would use this as if it were any other range:

```
for (std::string const& s : o.GetStringIterator()) {
    // ...
}
```

This loop does not copy any strings. Each `s` refers directly into the corresponding `string` that the `map` is storing.

Comment: In C++ 14 you even can drop off return type in the `GetStringIterator` declaration.